# how to write a client application for monotorrent with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, monotorrent

I'm trying to write a client app using monotorrent library with asp.net.
there is a clientapp sample provided by monotorrent but since I'm using asp.net I need to know how to keep the engine running all the time and get feedback, like download rate and ..

I tried to use the Task class provided in .NET 4, but the thread keeps shutting down randomly ( I think of course ).
Is there a way that I can keep the thread which engine is running in, always working?
or any idea on where to look for implementing the client in web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats impossible, as the ASP.NET worker process is recycled from time to time. What do you need is a desktop application or a windows service. And then build an WCF service to communicate with you ASP.net application.